# DRF how to filter user and product by Foreign key company?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

How can I filter by Foreign key(company) to get Only those product which got same company and authorized user?
Idea is user view information only about company in which he exist

**models:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True, null=True)
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializer**

```
class ProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**view**

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializers
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter Product based on the current User's company?

Something like:

`products = Product.objects.filter(company=user.company)`

Comment: thank you! U push me to right answer , I use `def get_queryset(self):` where make this check

Comment: Hi @Juliak - if my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. If you still need more help, please edit your question and add in the additional code you are having trouble with and I'll try to assist! Thanks!